$\det(AB-BA)=0$
Let $A,B$ be two $(2n+1) \times (2n+1)$ matrices with complex entries such that $A^2B^2 = (AB)^2$
Prove that $\det(AB-BA)=0$
If $A$ and $B$ are both invertible the problem is easy to solve. Otherwise I don't know where to start.

With "by calculation", what do you mean exactly? You checked it for specific matrices $A, B$?

In fact, $0$ doesn't have to be an eigenvalue.

Yeah, I checked for 3 different possibilities

@AnotherUser is there a way to calculate the spectrum?

As @AnotherUser said, $0$ doesn't have to be an eigenvalue. Take $A = \begin{pmatrix} -3 & 0 \ -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & -1 \ 6 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$. Both have eigenvalues $1$ and $2$, but their difference has eigenvalues $\frac{-7 \pm \sqrt{21}}{2}$

This question came from a problem that I have difficulties solving, if you'd like I'll post the problem

I have modified the question

Might be helpful to note that
$$
A(AB - BA)B = A^2B^2 - (AB)^2  = 0.
$$
This is obviously helpful in the case where $A$ and $B$ are invertible, but I suspect it might be helpful more generally as well

What properties of determinants are you allowed to assume?

Since $A$ and $B$ are of odd dimension, you will probably have to prove that $\operatorname{det}(AB-BA) = -\operatorname{det}(AB-BA) = \operatorname{det}(BA-AB)$ (the first equality implies it's zero, the second equality is because we take out a $(-1)^{2n+1} = -1$. So, you should prove $\operatorname{det}(AB-BA) = \operatorname{det}(BA-AB)$.
